# Not able to change owner field on creating new records

Tags: apex, custom-object, custom-field

Owner field is by default setting to my name.I want to have owner field as a lookup to user.Currently owner field is set to Lookup(User,Queue).How can i achieve my requirement with owner field as editable not static.

Comment: did you ever get a satisfactory answer? I have a very similar issue. In addition, I'd like to be able to transfer via a workflow rather than apex.

Answer (score 1):

If you want make owner field editable or changing owner filed then you need permission to do it.

One way to do this is to configure the user's profile to "Transfer Records". Check the Transfer Records check box to change the owners.

Here is more info from salesforce's online help:
The ability to change ownership of records depends upon user permissions, sharing as established by the organization wide defaults, and the role hierarchy. The following rules apply for record transfers:

1. System Administrators can transfer all records.
2. Standard Users can transfer ownership of any lead, contact, account, case or opportunity record that he/she owns or that is owned by a user below him/her in the role hierarchy (except campaigns).
3. Only users with the Marketing User check box selected on their personal information page can transfer campaigns.
4. If your organization wide defaults are set to Public Read/Write/Transfer for cases or leads, all users can transfer that type of record. If the organization wide defaults are more stringent, the rules outlined above apply.
5. For Enterprise Edition users, certain permissions can also affect the ability to change record ownership, like "Modify all Data"  and "Transfer Records".
6. Users with the "Transfer Record" permission can transfer any account, contact, lead, case or opportunity individually or in mass.
7. Users with the "Transfer Leads" and "Manage Leads" permissions can transfer any lead individually or in mass.
8. Users with the "Modify All Data" permission can transfer ownership of all records.

*Please note that users who have the ability to edit a record do not necessarily have the ability to transfer it.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this through APEX code as

> recirdInstance.OwnerID = user.ID

Where, user is the user record to whom you intend to make the owner

Comment: When u create any custom object owner field is added by default.For me also i want to make owner field as editable with owner field as a lookup to user.Above is not the correct solution i think.It will be only configuration and customization but not any coding as such involved.